# Need Regex for Uppercase Word

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract only **UPPERCASE words** (eg. AMXS, not Hello) in Java.
**Sample String:** Quick looks: ABM, AXR, D, AF; earnings previews; US abc vs. xyz markets; DRE Peru pipeline

**Expected O/P:** ABM AXR D AF US DRE

I tried with regex ([A-Z]), but its getting **Q and P** as well.

Comment: `\\b[A-Z]+\\b` ...

Comment: @ScaryWombat My question is specific to uppercase words only. the word Quick is not a uppercase word. I hope you are clear now

Comment: @AvinashRaj Its works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: JAVA is a bad example of an uppercase word :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're missing the word-break `\\b` in your Regex... This works as expected I believe.

```
String input = "Quick looks: ABM, AXR, D, AF; earnings previews; US abc vs. xyz markets; DRE Peru pipeline FOO";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+)\\b");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
ABM
AXR
D
AF
US
DRE
FOO
```